# Need to do refresh for displaying array that coming in json data and displaying through ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, json, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am receiving a response from backend and  saving in "allinfo" varable in my controller. Response data receiving is: name of person, DOB of person and Hobby of person. Hobby of person is array which is can be in n nos.

In my view i had apply ng repeat ovr all info as info in allinfo and for repeating hobby as hobs in info.hobby.

Problem I am facing is while I repeat the info in allinfo in my view, it display name and Dob but for hooby I need to do refreshand then it display hobby.

I had console the response and found that Hobby object is received in allinfo but thing is it is receiving empty array and after one refresh it refresh the all element of array.

Help me out in this. Thank you in advance

Comment: Please share some code.

Comment: actually i m not having code right now. I will share it after sometime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this it will work as per your expectation.

In below code i assume that `responseData` having the same format of the data as you are getting from the server.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.responseData = [
             {
             "name" : "Alpha",
             "dob" : "04-11-1991",
             "hobby" : [["singing"],["writing"]]
             },
             {
             "name" : "Beta",
             "dob" : "04-11-1990",
             "hobby" : [["playing"],["making friends"]]
             }
    ];
    
    var hobbiesData = [];
    for (var i in $scope.responseData) {
      hobbiesData = [];
      for (var j in $scope.responseData[i].hobby) {
        for(var k in $scope.responseData[i].hobby[j])
        hobbiesData.push($scope.responseData[i].hobby[j][k]);
      }
          var hobbies = hobbiesData.join();
          $scope.responseData[i].hobby = hobbies;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="data in responseData">
         Name : {{data.name}}<br>
         Date of Birth : {{data.dob}}<br>
         Hobbies : {{data.hobby}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this.one more thing I would like to mention that in my ng repeat of hobby as hobs in info.hobb, i had also used join(',')  so that array coming as "hobby" : [[playing],[making friends]"]coming  should separated by comma. Sorry for lately saying this thing.This is corrected one. Now how would you change this according to this corrected code

Comment: But hobby array is coming with comma seperated only.check `code snippet`

Comment: yes your are very correct but by mistakenly i forget to mention that in my response i m receiving arrays of array like    "hobby" : [[playing][making friends]]. So if now apply ng repeat here then it display output as Hobbies : [playing][making friends].Thats why i used join, and then it on REFRESH it displays as Hobbies : playing,making friends. I know, I m making mistake somewhere.. i am newbee in angualrjs.

Comment: @Mohammed I updated the code as per your change request. Please check now. I hope it will work as per your requirement.

Comment: @Mohammed did you checked the answer ?..if it is working as per your requirement please mark it as a correct answer so that it will be beneficial for others also.

Comment: unable to get solution..Error presist.

Comment: But i updated the answer as per your requirement and its working fine. Do you want any other changes ?

Comment: Ya that was correct.There was error in my implementation.working fine now.